# Modal Window Not Scaling Correctly for non-Admin users

Tags: 2013, permissions, list-form

I am decidedly a novice in SharePoint and have been attempting to build a page in SharePoint 2013 with likely not the appropriate level of knowledge for what I'm trying to do. :)   Regardless, though web-searches and trial and error, I have managed to achieve two of my objectives:  Hiding the top-of-page navigation bar for non-admin users and also removing the left-hand navigation panel for all users.

Unfortunately, somewhere along the line, the changes I've input have yielded an unfortunate side-effect.  When launching the modal window for a list form (built using InfoPath) the dialog box does not scale properly (only part of the form is visible within the window) and there is no vertical scroll bar to allow users to scroll up and down to view the entire form.

This scaling/scrolling issue does not present for users with Full Control. This makes it a little difficult for me to troubleshoot, but I'm also hampered by the fact that I'm quite the neophyte. :)  As I've jumped in the proverbial deep end without proper swimming lessons, I'm hoping that I can get a lifeguard to help me out without chastising me too badly for not staying in shallow waters. :)

Any help or guidance is appreciated - I will do my best to provide any additional information needed as to what changes have already been made to my site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Any time something works differently for non-owners, the most likely explanation is a permission issue. My guess is you have a CSS or JavaScript file in the master page gallery (or somewhere else) that is not checked in.

Comment: Thank you for responding!  As far as I can see, everything is checked in appropriately.  I have edited the master page to hide the top navigation bar with the following script:

<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
 <div id="s4-ribbonrow"
 …
</div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

Which, as it keys in to the ManageWeb permissions, I believe may be part of the issue.   Non-admin users have the top nav bar hidden correctly though, so I know that the changes are saved/published for all users...

Comment: I have validated that this SecurityTrimmedControl tag is the culprit; upon changing Permissions to 'FullMask' on my master I have been able to replicate the issue reported by users.  I will continue to poke at this now that I know the cause, but if there are suggestions as to better remove the top nav bar without affecting the modal window, please advise.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Upon further analysis and research, I have resolved my issue by adding another tag directly after the second SecurityTrimmedControl script/tag:

```
 <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="display:none;"></div>
```

This has corrected my modal window/dialog box so that it displays properly for users who have the ribbonrow hidden.  :)